# doesNotRecognizeSelector equivalent in Java

Tags: java, android, exception

Is there an equivalent or a hack to catch unimplemented method call in Java like we can do with doesNotRecognizeSelector in Objective C. I'm looking for a way to have an object replying to any method call with a default behavior when the method is not implemented ? Is it possible to use such a pattern in Java ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UnsupportedOperationException` which will do similar thing.

Comment: Mmm, that's a solution by it won't be very efficient to call to often as I suppose exception are computationaly expensive to call.

Comment: Correct!!but this is the way i can think of currently, lets wait for others response.

Comment: @CodeFlakes What problem do you believe you're trying to solve? You simply can't call an arbitrary method on a Java object unless you're using reflection. If you have a base class, you can implement a stub method that returns a known value, otherwise I don't really know what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm working on some kind of "agent based system" where I need an object to forward a method call when it's not capable of handling it itself.

Comment: @CodeFlakes Make sure to use the `@` sign or people won't know you're replying to them. As I said, you cannot call arbitrary methods on Java objects without using reflection. In other words, there is no "send an arbitrary message" to an instance. If you have an interface, and an implementing class does not implement that method, an exception is the correct approach. If you're calling un-implemented methods a lot, I question the design.

Comment: @DaveNewton Ok got it. Thank you Dave. I'll check Risi's answer has the right answer as it technically does what I wanted to do also not realistically usable in a real world project.

Comment: @CodeFlakes Don't know why it isn't usable. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

To "any" method call?

You can't *make* a method call to objects that don't implement a method, it wouldn't compile. Unless you're talking about via reflection, in which case, refleection itself will throw an exception.

If you're talking about an empty, "don't call me" method, then Rishi's answer is likely best.